# How do I remove textured paint from my patio floor?

Tags: concrete, patio, porch, texture, paint-removal

My patio flooring has a paint-like texture on it that is chipping off. The base is concrete. I have tried scraping, but it's incredibly tedious to get up and is taking hours of work. Is there some sort of chemical or solution I can use to help the paint/texture lift easier?

Comment: We'd need photos to give a good assessment. To post photos: [edit] your question and hit the sun-and-mountain icons just above.  To post photos from a different browser/device: Stop and register your account (tie it to an email/password, Facebook or Google reg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "paint-like" texture. Are you sure it's paint?

If it's paint, any sort of chemical paint stripper should do the trick. There are quite a number of more "friendly" "citrus" or "orange" based paint strippers that don't have the smell and toxic concerns of paint strippers of the past.

I presume a patio is outdoors, so a pressure washer may do the trick. Aim the blast at the currently chipped edges to allow the water to get underneath them and lift. You may need to shoot the water almost horizontally for the more stubborn bits. Aiming at a fairly well covered area is unlikely to get a hole started. If you've got enough pressure to do that, though, you've got a non-zero chance of actually damaging the concrete underneath, too, so turn down the pressure.

It's possible that you've got an epoxy coating instead of paint.  I'm not certain if the "friendly" strippers will work on that, you'll probably have to get one that's specifically for epoxy coating. Also, the pressure washer may not work so well on epoxy - it tends to grip pretty well.

If you're not sure what you've got, try taking a few flakes (the bigger the better) to a local paint store to see if the can ID it for you and make a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Your patio flooring has been painted over top of concrete.

The problem is, when you do that, the surface tends to become impossibly slick - it's not so bad *bone dry*, but get a drop of oil and some condensation, the oil will spread all over and the water will multiply with it to make the the surface **shockingly slick**.

This being a known vulnerability of painted concrete floors, they sell **traction modifiers** for painters to apply to the pant, to create a roughness which makes the surface safe to walk on in all conditions.

Paint manufacturers sell traction modifiers compatible withtheir paint.  But lots of peoplesay "I ain't paying $13 for a quart of sand", so they use a quart of sand.  And it may have compatibility issues with the paint.

**Regardless -- you *need* traction modifier**. If you're going to remove it, you will need to repaint, and in that paint coating, include your own traction modifier.

A glassy smooth surface is simply not an option from a safety POV.

Comment: Valuable info, but the OP was asking how to strip the old paint, not apply new. May have been better to be pared down into an "FYI - for future reference" type comment.

Answer (score 0):

**If you can't beat em, join em.**

If you can get the old stuff off, you probably will want some sort of treatment on your concrete porch.  So
maybe you could just put the new stuff on top.
Of course if the old stuff is totally flaking away then the new stuff will not adhere but it sounds like the old stuff is pretty tenacious.    If as @FreeMan suggests the old stuff is epoxy a new coat might adhere to and cover the old stuff and look good.

Comment: Applying new paint, which wasn't asked about, whether to siding, a door, or a concrete patio relies on having a well prepared surface. Adding new paint on top will allow the chipped edges of the old paint to show right through.

Comment: @Freeman I - is that true also for epoxy concrete coatings?  I thought they went on thicker than house paint.

Comment: It might, but prep-work is always the key to a good, long lasting paint job. No matter what kind of "paint" is used nor the surface below it. If, for example, you have a smooth, slick surface (like a highly polished car paint), it needs to be lightly scuffed up to create a "key" so the new paint can stick. Otherwise the new stuff will fall off fairly quickly.